# How to align Active tab at center for Scrollable Tabs in ReactJs (Web Platform)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have 8 items in sliding tab. **While sliding from left to right or as vice versa, selected active tab should be center exact same as play store top-bar.** Please help me how to do that in Web platform. I'm using Material-UI Components.
Please follow this reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/n5uch

Also please advice me how to add custom css like change the Trasition duration, Hover color etc.

I'm sharing the Code with some modification:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import SwipeableViews from 'react-swipeable-views';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`scrollable-auto-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`scrollable-auto-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `scrollable-auto-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `scrollable-auto-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: '100%',
  },
}));

export default function ScrollableTabsButtonAuto() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  const handleChangeIndex = (index) => {
    setValue(index);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static" color="default">
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="auto"
          aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
          style={{alignItems: 'center'}}
        >
          <Tab style={{marginLeft: 20}} label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab style={{marginLeft: 20}} label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab style={{marginLeft: 20}} label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
          <Tab style={{marginLeft: 20}} label="Item Four" {...a11yProps(3)} />
          <Tab style={{marginLeft: 20}} label="Item Five" {...a11yProps(4)} />
          <Tab style={{marginLeft: 20}} label="Item Six" {...a11yProps(5)} />
          <Tab style={{marginLeft: 20}} label="Item Seven" {...a11yProps(6)} />
          <Tab style={{marginLeft: 20}} label="Item Eight" {...a11yProps(7)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <SwipeableViews
        axis={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'x-reverse' : 'x'}
        index={value}
        onChangeIndex={handleChangeIndex}
      >
        <TabPanel value={value} index={0} dir={theme.direction}>
          Item One
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={1} dir={theme.direction}>
          Item Two
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={2} dir={theme.direction}>
          Item Three
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={3} dir={theme.direction}>
          Item Four
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={4} dir={theme.direction}>
          Item Five
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={5} dir={theme.direction}>
          Item Six
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={6} dir={theme.direction}>
          Item Seven
        </TabPanel>
        <TabPanel value={value} index={7} dir={theme.direction}>
          Item Eight
        </TabPanel>
      </SwipeableViews>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last example of Ant design for react native has the behavior you are looking for : [Ant Design Tabs](https://mobile.ant.design/components/tabs/)

You could try to use it instead of editing a component that is not made for this behavior.

Comment: Thank you sir i just checked and yes i was exactly talking about that. But their design is not what i want. Isn't there any way to implement that stuff in Scrollable Tab ??? I realy want it for my work. Please help! ----@QuentinGrisel

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible using `Tabs`. Instead, I had to create my own component to replace it:

```
import { Box, Tooltip, Typography, useTheme } from "@mui/material";
import { PageTabsProps } from "components/types";
import { createRef, useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

export type PageTab<T> = {
    color?: string,
    href?: string,
    /** If set, icon is displayed and label becomes a toolip */
    Icon?: SvgComponent;
    index: number,
    label: string,
    value: T
};

export type SxType = NonNullable<SystemStyleObject<Theme>> & {
    color?: string;
}

export interface PageTabsProps<T> {
    ariaLabel: string,
    currTab: PageTab<T>,
    fullWidth?: boolean,
    id?: string,
    onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<unknown>, value: any) => unknown,
    tabs: PageTab<T>[],
    sx?: SxType,
}

export const PageTabs = <T extends string | number | object>({
    ariaLabel,
    currTab,
    fullWidth = false,
    id,
    onChange,
    tabs,
    sx,
}: PageTabsProps<T>) => {
    const { breakpoints, palette } = useTheme();

    const tabsRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const tabRefs = useRef(tabs.map(() => createRef<HTMLDivElement>()));
    const underlineRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    // Handle dragging of tabs
    const draggingRef = useRef(false);
    const handleMouseDown = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
        if (tabsRef.current) {
            const startX = e.clientX;
            const scrollLeft = tabsRef.current.scrollLeft;
            const minimumDistance = 10; // Minimum distance in pixels for a drag
            let distanceMoved = 0; // Track the distance moved

            const handleMouseMove = (e: MouseEvent) => {
                if (!tabsRef.current) return;

                const x = e.clientX;
                const walk = (x - startX);
                distanceMoved = Math.abs(walk);

                // Only consider it a drag if the mouse has moved more than the minimum distance
                if (distanceMoved > minimumDistance) {
                    draggingRef.current = true;
                }
                // But still move the tabs even if it's not considered a drag
                tabsRef.current.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
            };

            const handleMouseUp = () => {
                // Only set draggingRef to false if it was considered a drag
                if (distanceMoved > minimumDistance) {
                    setTimeout(() => { draggingRef.current = false; }, 50);
                }
                document.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
                document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
            };

            document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);
            document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    };

    const handleTabChange = useCallback((event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
        if (draggingRef.current) return;
        // Add transition for smooth animation of underline
        if (underlineRef.current) {
            underlineRef.current.style.transition = "left 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease";
        }
        // Call onChange prop
        onChange(event, tabs[newValue]);
    }, [onChange, tabs]);

    // Scroll so new tab is centered
    const easeInOutCubic = (t: number) => t < 0.5 ? 4 * t * t * t : (t - 1) * (2 * t - 2) * (2 * t - 2) + 1;
    useEffect(() => {
        const selectedTab = tabRefs.current[currTab.index].current;
        if (!selectedTab || !tabsRef.current) return;

        const targetScrollPosition = selectedTab.offsetLeft + selectedTab.offsetWidth / 2 - tabsRef.current.offsetWidth / 2;
        const startScrollPosition = tabsRef.current.scrollLeft;
        const duration = 300;
        const startTime = performance.now();

        const animateScroll = (time: number) => {
            // Calculate the linear progress of the animation
            const linearProgress = Math.min((time - startTime) / duration, 1);

            // Apply the easing function to the linear progress
            const easedProgress = easeInOutCubic(linearProgress);

            const newScrollPosition = startScrollPosition + (targetScrollPosition - startScrollPosition) * easedProgress;
            if (tabsRef.current) tabsRef.current.scrollLeft = newScrollPosition;

            if (linearProgress < 1) {
                requestAnimationFrame(animateScroll);
            }
        };

        requestAnimationFrame(animateScroll);
    }, [currTab.index]);

    const updateUnderline = useCallback(() => {
        if (tabsRef.current && underlineRef.current) {
            const tabsContainer = tabsRef.current;
            const underlineElement = underlineRef.current;
            const activeTab: HTMLElement = tabsContainer.children[currTab.index] as HTMLElement;

            if (activeTab) {
                // Get the margin values
                const margin = getComputedStyle(activeTab).marginLeft || "0";
                const marginValue = parseFloat(margin);

                // Adjust the offsetLeft and offsetWidth by the margin
                const leftPosition = activeTab.offsetLeft - marginValue;
                const width = activeTab.offsetWidth + marginValue * 2;

                underlineElement.style.left = `${leftPosition}px`;
                underlineElement.style.width = `${width}px`;
            }
        }
    }, [currTab.index]);

    useEffect(() => {
        updateUnderline();
    }, [currTab.index, updateUnderline]);

    // Update underline on scroll
    useEffect(() => {
        const tabsContainer = tabsRef.current;
        if (tabsContainer) {
            const handleScroll = () => {
                if (underlineRef.current) {
                    underlineRef.current.style.transition = "none";
                }
                updateUnderline();
            };
            tabsContainer.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
            return () => {
                tabsContainer.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
            };
        }
    }, [updateUnderline]);

    // Update underline on window resize
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
            updateUnderline();
        };
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        };
    }, [tabs.length, updateUnderline]);

    // Update underline after short delay when tab length changes
    useEffect(() => {
        const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            updateUnderline();
        }, 100);
        return () => {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        };
    }, [tabs.length, updateUnderline]);

    return (
        <Box
            id={id}
            ref={tabsRef}
            role="tablist"
            onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
            sx={{
                minWidth: fullWidth ? "100%" : undefined,
                maxWidth: "100%",
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "flex-start",
                alignItems: "center",
                position: "relative",
                // Hide scrollbars
                overflowX: "scroll",
                whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                scrollbarWidth: "none", // for Firefox
                msOverflowStyle: "none", // for Internet Explorer 11
                "&::-webkit-scrollbar": {
                    display: "none", // for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
                },
                // Apply custom styles
                ...sx,
            }}
        >
            {tabs.map(({ color, href, Icon, label }, index) => {
                const isSelected = currTab.index === index;
                const tabColor = color ?? palette.primary.light;
                return (
                    <Tooltip key={index} title={Icon ? label : ""}>
                        <Box
                            id={`${ariaLabel}-${index}`}
                            ref={tabRefs.current[index]}
                            role="tab"
                            component={href ? "a" : "div"}
                            href={href}
                            aria-selected={isSelected}
                            aria-controls={`${ariaLabel}-tabpanel-${index}`}
                            onClick={(event) => handleTabChange(event, index)}
                            style={{
                                padding: "10px",
                                margin: fullWidth ? "0 auto" : "0",
                                cursor: "pointer",
                                textTransform: "uppercase",
                                // Darken non-selected tabs
                                filter: isSelected ? "none" : "brightness(0.8)",
                            }}
                        >
                            {Icon ? <Icon fill={tabColor} /> : <Typography variant="body2" style={{ color: tabColor }}>{label}</Typography>}
                        </Box>
                    </Tooltip>
                );
            })}
            <div
                ref={underlineRef}
                style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    bottom: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    height: "3px",
                    backgroundColor: palette.secondary.main,
                    transition: "left 0.3s ease, width 0.3s ease",
                }}
            />
        </Box>
    );
};
```